# URL redirection and TCP proxy in haproxy

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy, haproxy, tcp, redirection

In a server with only one ipv4 and running haproxy, i want to redirect an url and proxy another in TCP level, for ssl passthrough purpose.

```
frontend https-frontend
  bind *:443
  mode tcp
  option tcplog
  tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
  tcp-request content accept if { req_ssl_hello_type 1 }
  use_backend proxy-backend if { req.ssl_sni -i proxied-url.com }
  redirect prefix https://url-rewrited.com code 301 if  { req.ssl_sni -i domain-for-redirect.com }
```

But redirect prefix requires http mode, and proxy passthrough requires tcp mode.

```
[WARNING] 347/153600 (1324) : config : 'redirect' rules ignored for frontend 'https-frontend' as they require HTTP mode.
```

If I use two frontends binding in 443, errors occur when loading pages.

How can I proceed?

EDIT

I tried to do a http backend for redirection

```
frontend https-frontend
  bind *:443
  mode tcp
  option tcplog
  tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
  tcp-request content accept if { req_ssl_hello_type 1 }
  use_backend proxy-backend if { req.ssl_sni -i proxied-url.com }
  use_backend redirect-backend if  { req.ssl_sni -i domain-for-redirect.com }

backend redirect-backend
  mode http
  option ssl-hello-chk
  redirect prefix https://url-rewrited.com code 301 if { req.ssl_sni -i domain-for-redirect.com }
```

But when I go to domain-for-redirect.com I get ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR. How can I load the certificate in the backend?

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the ssl option with valid or self signed ssl certificate:
instead :
bind *:443
use:
bind    *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/private/certFileName.pem